# PHP Search Script not working

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to run a simple PHP search script that will show look through my mySQL database and present the results on a separate page that I've created. When I run the code, my results don't show up. Can someone please help me?? This is the code that i'm currently using:

```
<?php

    error_reporting(E_A`enter code here`LL);
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);

        $k = $_GET['k'];
        $terms = explode(" ", $k);
        $query = "SELECT * FROM search WHERE ";

        $i = 0;
        foreach ($terms as $each){
            $i++; 

            if ($i == 1) 
            {
                $query .= "keywords LIKE '%$each%' ";
            }           
            else
            {
                $query .= "OR keywords LIKE '%$each%' ";
            }   
    }

        // connect
        mysql_connect("josetogbecom.fatcowmysql.com","username","password");
        mysql_select_db("gff_hff6a144eg");

        $query = mysql_query($query);
        $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
        if ($numrows > 0){

            while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
                $id = $row['id'];
                $title = $row['title'];
                $description = $row['description'];
                $keywords = $row['keywords'];
                $link = $row['link'];

                echo "<h2><a href='$link'>$title</a></h2>
                $description<br /><br />";
            }   

        }
        else 
        {
            echo "No Search Results Were Found for \"<b>$k<b>\"";
        }


        // disconnect
        mysql_close();

    ?>

Thanks in advance!
```

Comment: You have a username and password in clear text! Edit it, quick!

Comment: Thanks, I just changed my password info

Comment: **error_reporting(E_A`enter code here`LL);** this is wrong, should be **error_reporting(E_ALL);**.

Answer (score 1):

Check if your `$i` counter var is set to `$i=0` before `foreach` loop

Answer (score 1):

**Bug at this line:**

```
echo "No Search Results Were Found for \"<b>$k<b>/"";
```

Should be:

```
echo "No Search Results Were Found for \"<b>$k<b>\"";
```

**Bug at this line:**

```
mysql close();
```

Should be:

```
mysql_close();
```

**Bug at this line:**

```
$i++;
```

You should always initialize your variables, like this:

```
$i = 0;
foreach ($terms as $each){
    $i++;

    if ($i == 1)
        $query .= "keywords LIKE '$each%' ";
    else
        $query .= "OR keywords LIKE '$each%' ";
}
```

---

If the script still doesn't work after correcting these two bugs, add to the beginning of the script these 2 lines and tell us what you see:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Comment: Thanks! but the search results are still not appearing!

Comment: @user3417199 If still nothing than add those last two lines right after `<?php` and tell us what you see.

Comment: this is what I see: 0){ while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){ $id = $row['id']; $title = $row['title']; $description = $row['description']; $keywords = $row['keywords']; $link = $row['link']; echo "
$title
$description

"; }  } else { echo "No Search Results Were Found for \"$k\""; } // disconnect mysql_close(); ?>

Comment: My script worked! I just wanted to thank you all for helping and being patient!

Comment: @user3417199 No problem, thats what this site is for.

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to make multiple search results appear, just like it would on Google. For now only one result is appearing. Can you help?